# Finding constants with a piecewise continuous function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

Let $$f(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{3x^{2}+ax+a+3}{x^{2}+x-2}, & x \neq -2 \\ b & x= -2 \end{cases}$$

Given that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=-2$, find $a$ and $b$.

Above is the problem I'm working on. With my limited knowledge, I know from this that $$\lim\limits_{x \to -2} f(x)=f(-2)=b$$

And I also know that because it's given that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=-2$,$$\lim\limits_{x \to -2} \frac{3x^{2}+ax+a+3}{x^{2}+x-2}=b$$

But this is where I come undone. I can't seem to make a leap. I don't want to go through the pain of guess and check. We've just been introduce to limits in the course I'm doing now and I'm unsure as to how to move forward with this problem.

I've tried following the train of thought:

$$\lim\limits_{x \to -2} \frac{3x^{2}+ax+a+3}{x^{2}+x-2}=b$$
$$=\lim\limits_{x \to -2} \frac{3x^{2}+ax+a+3}{(x+2)(x-1)}$$
$$=\lim\limits_{x \to -2} \frac{3(x^{2}+1)+a(x+1)}{(x+2)(x-1)}$$

But then I get lost and confused again. Feeling like a bit of a duffer at the moment. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you all below. You all responded at a similar time with the same answer haha. Cheers for the insight. It's always some piece of logic that I miss. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the denominator approaches $0$ as $x\to -2$. So as $x\to -2$, the numerator must approach $0$, else the limit could not exist.

But as $x\to -2$, the numerator approaches $3(-2)^2+(-2)a+a+3$. This is $0$, so $a=15$.

Finding $b$ is left to you.  As a hint, the numerator, with $a$ replaced by $15$, must be divisible by $x+2$. Do the division.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, as long as the denominator is going to $0$ for $x\to -2$ and the nominator
not, the whole thing goes to infinity, plus or minus. So what you need to do, is to find a value for $a$ such that the nominator has the form $(x+2).....$, then
the factors cancel and you get a finite limit as $x\to -2$. And then you are almost done ;-).

Comment: The problem with the two other answers is that they do not make clear that the condition $lim_{x \to -2} g(x) =0$ works here only because the denominator has a simple zero at $-2$.  If there would be a double zero,i.e. the denominator equal to $(x+2)^2(x-1)$ for example, this would not work. To get a real limit unequal zero, the orders of the zeros in denominator and nominator have to be the same.

Answer (score 2):

For convenience, let $g(x) = 3x^2+ax+a+3$. Note that if $g(-2) \neq 0$, then the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow -2} \frac{g(x)}{(x+2)(x-1)}$ does not exist. But since the limit exists, we must have $g(-2) = 0$. This implies that $a = 15$.